# Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 Forged HELO

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 Forged HELO .

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 Forged HELO .

```
    Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
    MailMessage msg;
    string ActivationUrl = string.Empty;
    string emailId = string.Empty;                                
    msg = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    emailId = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("******");
    msg.To.Add(emailId);
    msg.Subject = "Confirmation E-mail";
    msg.Body = str2;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*********", "**********");
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.Host = "***********";
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;                                
    smtp.Send(msg);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Confirmation Link to activate your account has been sent to your email address');", true);                                                                
    Response.Redirect("Successfull.aspx");
```

My web.config file

```
<configuration>    
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=***.**.***.**;Database=***********;Integrated Security=false;Uid=**********;Pwd=**********;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
      <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Server=***.**.***.**;Database=************;User ID=*****************;Password=*****************;" />
      </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    </system.web>
  <system.web>
  <machineKey validationKey="**************************************" decryptionKey="****************************************************" validation="****" decryption="***" />
  </system.web>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What mail server are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you have no SSL/TLS on your server?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and I was able to fix the issue by changing the mail settings in code. Actually, I was using different email-id in:

---

```
msg.From = new MailAddress("******");



smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*********", "**********");
```

---

So,I used same email-id in SMTP authentication and From Address.